# State which of the following Ito integrals exist, calculate its mean and variance.

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

State if the Ito integral exist for $\int_0^T sin(B_t)dB_t $ calculate its mean and variance.

After applying Ito's lemma this is what I got:

$B_0 = 0$

$sin(B_t) = \int_0^T cos(B_t)dB_t  - \frac 12 \int_0^T sin(B_t)dt $

I am a bit stuck on how to show its mean and variance.

Comment: What have you tried doing? What do you know?

Comment: @Saegusa I know that $B_t$ is normal distributed with mean 0 and variance t. I could use the Ito's isometry property but I don't know if I can do E(cos($B_t))^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\sin(\cdot)$ is bounded and hence $\int_0^T E(|\sin(B_t)|^2)dt<\infty$. This implies that the Itô integral is a martingale and hence it has $0$ mean.

For the variance apply the Itô isometry

$$E\left(\big|\int_0^T \sin(B_t)dB_t\big|^2\right)=E\left(\int_0^T \sin(B_t)^2dt\right)$$

Then you can apply Tonelli lemma to change the order of integration, and then calculate

$$E(\sin^2(B_t)).$$

To do so use the Euler formula $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and using the fact that $B_t$ is centered Gaussian with variance $t$ you can solve this expectation using the Characteristic function (I leave you this computations).
Then you can simply compute the time integral to obtain the variance.